# Join two tables and return data from either one or the other based on data

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. SQL 2012
2. Cannot change tables
3. Have two tables in question, both tables are identical
4. (I didn't design this)

Table A has application data.  We accept applications and at the time of application we require a minimum of information - many values here can be null (or some placeholder like NA etc).  It is assigned an application number (application id).  If the application is accepted, we require more information - and we verify it.

Leading us to Table B - a copy of A except it is only populated with accepted applications - and verified data.  So an application id will only exist in Table B if the manager accepts it.  Sometimes, at the application process, the data is correct and no changes were made - leading to an application id having the exact values in both tables.  Sometimes, the data changes or is added (we require all fields upon acceptance).

I would like to an easy way to capture all applications and the most current/verified data.

For instance:

```
Table A (Active Applications)
ApplicationID    Phone          State    
1234             123-456-7890    AK        
5678             246-802-4680    NULL      

Table B (Approved/Accepted Applications)
ApplicationID    Phone           State    
5678             246-802-4680     NY
```

Application 5678 was approved and, for demonstration only, the state was verified to be NY.
Application 1234 was not approved to date (but maybe in the future).

I would like to write a query which gives the following result:

```
ApplicationID    Phone           State
1234             123-456-7890     AK
5678             246-802-4680     NY
```

Desired behavior is essentially...return Table A unless the ApplicationID exists in Table then give me Table B instead.

Table A does contain every application expired or not, but there is an expiry date (applications good for 10 days) and it will be easy to cull those out based on that date.
Just flummoxed by needing approved and active applications.

Any help greatly appreciated.

--EDIT--
Thank you...but how do I handle the placeholders (like NA or XX) or when the verified data is deifferent from the application data?  Say there is a third active application as so:

```
    Table A (Active Applications)
    ApplicationID    Phone           State
    9876             234-432-1234     NY

    Table B (Approved Applications)
    ApplicationID    Phone           State
    9876             234-432-1234     TX
```

The application was accepted by virtue of its existance in Table B but the state was verified to be TX and not NY.

I would like to see an output as such...Table A data if not in Table B.  IF In Table B then Table B data.

```
ApplicationID     Phone          State
1234             123-456-7890     AK
5678             246-802-4680     NY
9876             234-432-1234     TX
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.applicationid, case when b.phone is null then a.phone else b.phone end as phone, case when b.state is null then a.state else b.state end as state
From a
Left outer join b on a.applicationid = b.applicationid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
a.applicationid as a1, a.phone as a2, a.state as a3,
b.applicationid as b1, b.phone as b2, b.state as b3,
isnull(b.applicationid, a.applicationid) as applicationid,
isnull(b.phone, a.phone) as phone,
isnull(b.state, a.state) as state
from a
left outer join b on a.applicationid=b.applicationid
```

(omit line 2 and 3, these are just to show what the column entries are before isnull())